# Whats wrong with this Data Explorer SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, syntax-error

I am trying to write a **How much did I type?** query on [Stack* Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Modifying an existing query got me this far:

```
-- How much did I type?

DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

  select sum(len(Body)) AS 'Posts' from posts where owneruserid = @UserId,
  select sum(len(Text)) AS 'Comments' from comments where userid = @UserId,
  (select sum(len(Body)) from posts where owneruserid = @UserId +
  select sum(len(Text)) from comments where userid = @UserId) AS 'Total'
```

I am expecting three columns and one row, something like this:

```
Posts    Comments    Total
1234     5678        6912
```

But there is some syntax problem, due to which I get:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near ','.
>   Incorrect syntax near ','. Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

**What is the correct syntax for this?**

Comment: The question is regarding http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new specifically. Random SQL queries are not helping.

Comment: @Aaron Harun: What is everyone doing wrong? Is it like Data Explorer supports only a subset of valid SQL queries?

Comment: Basically, yes. They need to be using TSQL, but some aren't.  (http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/home.asp) In most of the "wrong" examples, there are syntax errors and others they used different field names. *shrug* It happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working query:

```
DECLARE @UserId int;
set @UserID = 4;  

Select *, (Posts+Comments) as Total
FROM
  (select sum(len(Body)) AS Posts    FROM posts    where owneruserid = @UserId ) p,
  (select sum(len(Text)) AS Comments FROM comments where userid      = @UserId ) c
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way...

```
declare @ownerId int
set @ownerId = 1

declare @Posts bigint
declare @Comments bigint

select
@Posts = sum(len(Body))
from Posts where owneruserid = @ownerId

select
@Comments = sum(len(Text))
from Comments where userid = @ownerId

select @Posts as 'Posts', @Comments as 'Comments', @Posts + @Comments as 'Total'
```

Comment: Originally, I forgot to clear out the select statements before the "sum" statements.  It should be good now.

Comment: @Aaron Harun, thanks for pointing me to data explorer.  I totally overlooked that when I first viewed the question.  I ended up creating my own tables on my sql server (albeit with different table/column names).  Now  I know.

Answer (score 1):

Hi your problem is that you have 3 Statements concatenated to 1 Statement - just make one Statement out of if:
like

```
select sum(len(Body)) AS 'Posts', sum(len(Text)) AS 'Comments' , sum(len(Body)) + sum(len(Text)) AS Total
from posts t1 inner join comments t2 on t1.owneruserid = t2.userid 
where t1.owneruserid = @UserId
```

Hope I typed correct ...

Answer (score 0):

```
-- How much did I type?

/* If this is to be a parameter from your app, you don't need to declare it here*/
DECLARE @UserId int;
set @UserID = 4;  

Select *, (Posts+Comments) as Total
FROM 
  (select sum(len(Body)) AS Posts    FROM posts    where owneruserid = @UserId ) p,
  (select sum(len(Text)) AS Comments FROM comments where userid      = @UserId ) c
```